# Use local USB when connected via SSH

Tags: ssh, usb

Is there any way I can access a device plugged into the USB port of my local machine while connected to a remote machine via SSH?

What I am trying to do is set up a development environment in the cloud, and flash programs to a microcontroller connected via SSH.

Answer (score 14):

This assumes you are running Linux on both sides.  If you are running Windows, there are possibilities (like `putty` and `CygWin`), but it is a bit more difficult to do.

Yes, you probably can.  But this is very likely not want want to do:

- If you are flashing, what happens if the network connection breaks?
- Do you really want to allow a cloud to "infect" your local USB?

## Serial port

If your local USB device has something like a serial port for flashing, you perhaps can use some local port forwarding and `socat` to connect to the serial line.  Provided that your development environment allows to `flash` using a TCP port.  Like follows:

On your local machine: `ssh -R1234:localhost:1234 user@remote.example.com`

This opens port `127.0.0.1:1234` on `remote.example.com` which then connects to `127.0.0.1:1234` on your local machine.

Now you use `socat` to connect to the serial line of your `USB`:

On your local machine: `socat -d -d -d tcp-listen:1234,reuseaddr,fork,bind=127.0.0.1 /dev/ttyUSB0`

#### TCP -> Pipe

On the other side, if the software cannot use TCP but wants to talk to a pipe or tty, you can use `socat` again to provide that:

On the remote: `socat -d -d -d unix-listen:.mypipe tcp-connect:127.0.0.1:1234`

Now let your remote software connect to `.mypipe` and it is transparently connected to `/dev/ttyUSB0` on your local computer.

But your mileage may vary.  It depends heavily what your software in the cloud needs.

#### Special USB drivers

For example it may be that you need to create some special stub, which talks to `USB`.  Luckily this can be forked of by socat as well:

On the local side: `socat -d -d -d tcp-listen:1234,reuseaddr,fork,bind=127.0.0.1 exec:/path/to/program`

The remote side is more difficult, because if it expects to talk to `USB`, you probably need to create some dummy USB driver for the Linux kernel and load it there.  Not easy to manage, sorry.

### To sum it up

`SSH` in combination with `socat` is able to provide nearly all the interconnection between your local machine and "the cloud" you might think of.

However connecting to a local `USB` may or may not need some special treatment, on both sides.  The problematic part is not `SSH` or `socat`, it is how to allow the remote software to talk over such a tunnel to your local USB.

Perhaps somebody else knows some `plug and play USB emulator` for Linux, but I never came across such a beast.  And I do Linux for nearly 20 years now ..

As a starting point, [perhaps look at that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913979/how-to-emulate-usb-devices)